# What is the benefit to disable "Quick Boot" in Android Phone?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, micromax-a89

> Device : MMX A89
>  OS : ICS 4.0.4

What is the benefit to Disable "Quick Boot" in Android Smart Phones?

I am most concerned about MMX A89 first. And it would be great if could also know about general case. But first and foremost for MMX A89.

Comment: Are you talking about general or related to your device as per the [tag:micromax-a89]? Its not clear in what you're asking.

Comment: @t0mm13b, I have updated the question to answer your question :)

Comment: Ok, why would you want to disable quick boot? And by quick boot, you are referring to what? Or is that where you hold down the menu key upon boot to *boot into safe-mode*?

Comment: @t0mm13b, I was reading one of comment on Android Mobile where reviewer has just written that Disable Quick Boot to improve performance. So I am curious that How Quick Boot can improve performance?